# Communicating between an HTML page and Ruby script in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax

I have a webpage with 5 user input fields (1 text, 3 numerical, and a button to submit the input) and I have a ruby file that needs the data from these inputs to run a script and generate custom values. After it does this, I want to take those values (which are colour hex codes stored in an array) back to the HTML page and change the colour of separate elements on that page to those stored hex code values (they're currently styled in the CSS). I'll try to draw out an example below: (I'm using - as empty lines for formatting)

**Index.html.erb**

```
<div class="element_one">Change my colour to output[0]!</div>
<div class="element_two">Change my colour to output[1]!</div>
etc..
-
<input class="text_input" id="input1" type="text" />
<label for="input1">Input Text</label>
-
<input class="num_input" id="input2" type="number" />
<label for="input2">Input Num</label>
-
<input class="num_input" id="input3" type="number" />
<label for="input3">Input Num</label>
-
<input class="num_input" id="input4" type="number" />
<label for="input4">Input Num</label>
-
<button class="button" id="generate" type="button"/>
<label for="button">icon</label>
```

So 'input1' through 'input4' need to be sent to the following ruby file, app/lib/colorgen.rb (I believe this is the right directory to put it in) and then used in the place of my current *print "Input here" input = gets.chomp* placeholders.

**colorgen.rb**

```
print "Input1 here: "
input_one = gets.chomp.downcase
--code based on input_one--
```

etc. through input_four.

```
generated_results = (hex_one, hex_two, hex_three...)
```

The hex colour values stored in generated_results need to then be applied to the elements in each div in index.html.erb.

I know I need to use AJAX for this, but the tutorials I find assume prior knowledge I don't have and use custom placeholder terms that don't provide results when I google them.

Comment: The logic may live in `lib` but the request (ajax if you don't want to reload the page) must hit some controller, which will pass data to your logic, get return values and render a response.

Comment: And yes, there's no way you can do it with `gets`. You'll have to rewrite `colorgen.rb`

Comment: Yep the print input and gets.chomp part is a placeholder until I get the answer I'm looking for here. I really don't know how to build a controller to do this, just to make links on a page. I'm only a couple of weeks into programming in general.

Comment: In this case, can I interest you in a [tutorial](https://www.railstutorial.org/) or [the rails bible](https://pragprog.com/book/rails5/agile-web-development-with-rails-5)? :)

Comment: Or maybe some [interactive mentoring](https://www.codementor.io/stulentsev)?